# End-to-end symmetric encryption from Android app to Angular.JS Web app and back

Tags: android, angularjs, security, encryption, cryptography

I'm building an Android app that contains sensitive chat messages.

I'd really appreciate some help regarding an encryption workflow that allows me to encrypt these messages, store them in a remote database, query for them via Angular.JS and finally decrypt them and present them to the user.

The server must not be able to decrypt the messages. Only both Android and Angular.JS clients should be able to encrypt and decrypt the data, and the encryption key should be unique for each of my users. Both clients can send messages, so both need the ability to encrypt and decrypt.

Is there any way to get this done without requiring the user to enter a custom "Encryption Key" in both clients? Is there any way for this to be automatic in some way, and without involving the server? If not, what are the best-practices in this condition? I wasn't able to find any example of this kind of encryption in any wide-known service as of today.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're asking about how to do key exchange without revealing the key to the network, right?

[image]

[Diffie-Hellman key exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) is one well known algorithm for doing this. The important high level properties are that the two parties, in the end, agree on a shared secret that a passive eavesdropper can't get. However, the parties don't authenticate each other, so they can't tell if they're running the algorithm with a man in the middle (e.g., the server in your question).

I've seen products use [password-authenticated key exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password-authenticated_key_agreement). As the name suggests, these algorithms require that both parties (in this case, the same user, but on different devices) know a password. So ultimately, going with this approach requires the user to enter a password on one of the devices (the other can generate it and display it to the user). It's a little less troublesome than entering an entire encryption key into both devices, right?

As for technical implementations, it's still probably going to involve the server (or *a* server, if not the database server) just to relay messages, but these key exchange algorithms should keep the shared secret confidential.

> I wasn't able to find any example of this kind of encryption in any wide-known service as of today.

One great resource I've found is a page from Mozilla's wiki on how they implemented [key exchange in their Firefox Sync product](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Services/KeyExchange#Implementation). They use this when you set up Sync on multiple devices, which requires the second device to get the key from the first device.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think that the Diffie-Hellman exchange doesn't work in my case - when data needs to be encrypted, only the Android device is connected, so I can't communicate with the Web app yet. I think that the Firefox Sync product works in my case - I will let the user choose an additional Encryption Key and then ask him/her to enter it in the Web app. And I'll encrypt/decrypt using AES.